# Observable function in angular not returning everything in response

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function in an angular component that i call from a template, that function is of type Observable string, but unfortunately it doesn't return everything, only `data` variable. 
How can it be solved to return `dateNew[0] + " de " + data + " de "+ dateNew[2]`?

```
showDate(date):Observable<string>{
    let dateNew = this.datePipe.transform(this.dateTimePipe.transform(date), "dd/MM/yyyy").split('/');
    return this.translate.get(this.getMonthByNumber(dateNew[1])).do(data => {return dateNew[0] + " de " + data + " de "+ dateNew[2]});
}
```

I'm calling this function from an element

```
                    <h2 [innerHTML]="showDate(event?.data)|async">
                    </h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.showDate(date).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log('response = ' + res);
  },
  err => {console.log('error subscribing to showDate()');}
}
```

Comment: i'm calling the function from an html element, how can i do it that way?

Comment: use the async pipe... {{ showDate(date) | async }} https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: A little description of the code helps people better to understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

Observables are lazy collections of multiple values over time. Observables will return unless subscribe().

```
howDate(date).subscribe();
```

Comment: You can subscribe calling subscribe() `howDate(date).subscribe();`

Comment: that seems nice, but what if i'm calling the function from an html element?

Comment: @MohammadAliRony `AsyncPipe` accepts as an argument an observable or a promise and calls subscribe on it.

Comment: @Vikas Thanks:)

Comment: @Nmaster88 The async pipe does the subscription in view bindings. So you can {{ showDate(date) | async }}  or [innerHTML]="showDate(event?.data)|async".

Comment: for more information https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-async-data-binding-with-ng-if-and-ng-else